# How to set parameter values based on another parameter value but order of parameters is reverse?

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I want to set value of a parameter based on another parameter but order parameter is reverse and first parameter is set as hidden for internal use.

For example I have two parameters lets say Param1(Hidden) and Param2 now I want to set value of Param1 based on value selected in Param2 and in reports parameters section order of parameter is first Param1 and then Param2.

Currently I am getting below error when I try to do so:

```
The report parameter 'Param1' has a DefaultValue or ValidValue that depends on the report parameter "Param2".Forward dependencies are not valid.
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to change the order of the parameters.

Make *Parameter2* first so that *Parameter2* will have a value by the time *Parameter1* tries to populate itself.

Check out this link for changing parameter order: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255258.aspx

If you can't change the order of the parameters, then I would recommend adding another parameter (let's call it Parameter3).

Your parameter order should be *Parameter1*, *Parameter2*, *Parameter3*.  Set *Parameter3's* default value based on *Parameter2's* value.  Then update your report to use *Parameter3* instead of *Parameter1*.

Comment: Thanks for reply but as per my requirements I am not allowed to change order of parameters.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a solution if you can't change the order of the parameters.  Out of curiosity, why can't you change the order of the parameters?

Comment: Thanks for commenting but your updated solution also didn't worked for me as it is throwing same error. If you have tried this practically then can you give me screen details or screen shots of any demo report?